# More information on "cannot instantiate abstract class"

Tags: c++, abstract-class

Sometimes I am working with relatively complex (and sometimes confusing - with the way they are laid out by whoever wrote it originally) abstract classes. When inheriting from it, I sometimes encounter `cannot instantiate abstract class` and most of the time it is because I forgot to declare & implement a pure virtual function. Can I get more information from the compiler about which function it found I did not implement instead of hunting for it?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Then switch from the Error List tab to Output. There will be something like: `error C2259: 'foo' : cannot instantiate abstract class due to following members: [missing pure virtual members follow]`

Comment: @Fanael: Exactly what I required! I did not know the output printed that out. If you put that as an answer, I will check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Visual Studio? If so, then switch from Error List tab to Output tab. There will be something like:

```
main.cpp(8): error C2259: 'foo' : cannot instantiate abstract class
          due to following members:
          'void Foo::method(char)' : is abstract
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you encounter that message, then it immediately means that you have not defined a *pure* `virtual` function in the derived class, and you want to create an instance of it. And if you're using a good compiler then, I'm sure, it indicates which *pure* `virtual` function you didn't implement. At least, GCC indicates that.

See the error message here: http://www.ideone.com/83iDk

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   prog.cpp:11: error: cannot declare variable ‘a’ to be of abstract type ‘A’
>   prog.cpp:6: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘A’:
>   prog.cpp:7: note:   virtual void A::f()

That is more than enough that you didn't implement `A::f()`.

Comment: Visual Studio indicates that as well (thanks to Fanael for pointing it out). Thanks! (+1)